# They had often heard about the ship they have to travel on

Tags: tense, exam-questions

> They had often heard about the ship they have to travel on.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct ? I came across this sentence in a question paper and the *provisional* solution of that paper said it is error free but I suspect *have* is wrong here. It should be *had* as the sentence is in past ( as indicated by *they **had***)

Comment: The sentence makes perfect sense if the subject _they_ are about to travel on a ship which had previously been described to them, and on which they are somehow obligated to travel. It is certainly grammatically correct, in any case. What do you think is ungrammatical here?

Comment: @P.E.Dant I see your point, but the thing that I don't get is the necessity for the past perfect. I mean why the author didn't use "simple past"?

Comment: @Cardinal Admittedly, the situation that merits the past perfect is torturous and abstruse, but it might obtain. Without more context from the OP, we cam say no more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are idiomatic:

> I had heard about the unreliability of the train I had to take into
>   the city.
>
> I  heard about the unreliability of the train I had to take into
>   the city.
>
> I heard about the unreliability of the train I have to take into the
>   city.
>
> I have heard about the unreliability of the train I have to take into the
>   city.

When the restrictive clause is set in the present ("I have to take into the city" or *they have to travel on* in the original example), the present becomes the reference time, and so the tense in the matrix should be cast in the past or present perfect, not in the past perfect.

If the matrix clause is in the past perfect, there is an implicit relocation of the "origo" to some moment in the past.

> I had heard about the unreliability of the train I have to take into
>   the city.

and *I have to take into the city* doesn't jibe with that origo. To ease that temporal dissonance we could use **must** instead:

> I had heard about the unreliability of the train I **must** take into
>   the city.